# Sanic web framework performance

Tags: python-3.x, performance, sanic, asyncpg

I have a question to ask about sanic / asyncpg performance.

During a testing a weird things kept happening (Maybe it is by design).

First let me explain testing procedure. It is simple.

I use locust to push the server as much as possible by setting max user count.

The testing script is:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between


class UserActions(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def test_point_1(self):
        self.client.get(
            '/json_1',
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )

    @task(2)
    def test_point_2(self):
        self.client.get(
            '/json_2',
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )


class ApplicationUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserActions
    wait_time = between(0, 0)
```

It is used to test the following code. Notice asyncpg is calling potgresql sleep function to simulate a load:

```
import asyncio
import uvloop
from asyncpg import create_pool
from sanic import Sanic, response
from sanic.log import logger
import aiotask_context as context

app = Sanic(__name__)

DATABASE = {
    'type': 'postgresql',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'user': 'test_user',
    'port': '5432',
    'password': 'test_password',
    'database': 'test_database'
}

conn_uri = '{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}:{4}/{5}'.format(
            'postgres',
            DATABASE['user'], DATABASE['password'], DATABASE['host'],
            DATABASE['port'], DATABASE['database'])


@app.route("/json_1")
async def handler_json_1(request):
    async with request.app.pg.acquire() as connection:
        await connection.fetchrow('SELECT pg_sleep(0.85);')
    return response.json({"foo": "bar"})


@app.route("/json_2")
async def handler_json_2(request):
    async with request.app.pg.acquire() as connection:
        await connection.fetchrow('SELECT pg_sleep(0.2);')
    return response.json({"foo": "bar"})


@app.listener("before_server_start")
async def listener_before_server_start(*args, **kwargs):
    try:

        pg_pool = await create_pool(
            conn_uri, min_size=2, max_size=10,
            server_settings={'application_name': 'test_backend'})
        app.pg = pg_pool

    except Exception as bss_error:
        logger.error('before_server_start_test erred with :{}'.format(bss_error))
        app.pg = None


@app.listener("after_server_start")
async def listener_after_server_start(*args, **kwargs):
    # print("after_server_start")
    pass


@app.listener("before_server_stop")
async def listener_before_server_stop(*args, **kwargs):
    # print("before_server_stop")
    pass


@app.listener("after_server_stop")
async def listener_after_server_stop(*args, **kwargs):
    # print("after_server_stop")
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.set_event_loop(uvloop.new_event_loop())
    server = app.create_server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8282, return_asyncio_server=True)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_task_factory(context.task_factory)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(server)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as lerr:
        logger.error('Loop run error: {}'.format(lerr))
        loop.stop()
```

The issue is, after a random amount of time server becomes unresponsive 
(Does not return 503 or any other code) for a cca. 60 seconds.
Also process hangs (I can see it with `ps aux` and CTRL+C cannot kill it.)

That might be problematic because for one it is hard to detect and it is difficult to determine a rate at which we can send request to the server.

Could that be an issue with the configuration (sanic/asyncpg)?

Could setting nginx / sanic request timeout be the only option to circumvent this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your aiopg pool is limited to 10 connections. So 10 requests at a time max, each takes 0.2 sec, your max possible load would be 1 sec / 0.2 sec * 10 pool size = 50 RPS. After that all incoming requests would just wait for a connection and queue of requests to serve would grow much faster than your ability to serve and your server would become irresponsive.